# FullCalendar events JSON feed with slightly different response format

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and this is how I initialise it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: $('#calendar').data('source')
});
```

The problem is that the response is not in the format FullCalendar expects it as all the resultset is nested under data, i.e.

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "title": "Event1",
            "start": "2011-04-04"
        },
        {
            "title": "Event2",
            "start": "2011-04-04"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can provide a custom callback to make it use data element of the result as the event source?

I tried this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var url =  $('#calendar').data('source');
        $.get(url, {start: start, end: end, timezone: timezone})
        .done(function( data ) {
            callback(data.data);
        });
    }
});
```

But all I get is a JS error saying

> moment.min.js:22Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar'
>   of undefined

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. The error was coming not really from a FulLCalendar but Moment.js library

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#calendar').data('source'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                end: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            },
            success: function(result) {
                var events = [];
                result.data.forEach(function(element) {
                    events.push({
                        title: element.title,
                        start: element.start 
                    });
                });

                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It has helped!!